# Starting date and ending date are same using Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

Starting date and ending date are same. If change starting date automatically changed end date. Here my code

```
<input id="startingDate" class="datePicker form-control" name="startingDate" value="14-01-2017" type="text">

<input id="endingDate" class="datepicker form-control" name="endingDate" value="" type="text">
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).on('blur', '#startingDate', function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
    $("#endingDate").datetimepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
         defaultDate: date
    });
});
```

What is my problem and how i can solve that problem ??

Comment: I think you should change defaultDate to someting else like new Date() please check it, I have not tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the same value in endingDate when you leave your startingDate
you can do that's

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#startingDate").blur(function (){
                $("#endingDate").val($(this).val());
            });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Answer is right show the date in Ending text field but if i don't select any date in calender, ending date is empty. I want to specific date selected in calender as like starting date.